# Error while convert ova to ovf

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

I am using ovftool to convert ova to ovf . But i get this error

[image: Error Image]

I made ova file in virtual box and I want import in vmware esxi 5.5

Answer (score 0):

No need to convert, you can deploy an OVA natively in VMware. The only practical difference between an OVA and an OVF is that the OVA has all the files in one. Somewhat similar to a tarball (.tar).

See the image below from my VMware vSphere Client. Notice that both the `*.ovf; *ova` extensions are supported, and the OVA in my current directory is selectable.

[image]